# Retrieve ONLY new message from email

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I am trying to retrieve messages from an email address using Imaplib, so far i have been able to retrieve the messages, however, i am only interested in the original message, meaning that if the message is a "Re:" then i don't want the previous messages, i want only the new one, is this possible ?

heres what i get from python :

```
test # 10\r\n\r\nOn Thu, Dec 1, 2011 at 11:17 PM, paulo alvarado\r\n<commonzenpython@gmail.com>wrote:\r\n\r\n> test # 9\r\n>\r\n>\r\n> On Thu, Dec 1, 2011 at 11:15 PM, paulo alvarado <commonzenpython@gmail.com\r\n> > wrote:\r\n>\r\n>> test # 8\r\n>>\r\n>>\r\n>> On Thu, Dec 1, 2011 at 11:14 PM, paulo alvarado <\r\n>> commonzenpython@gmail.com> wrote:\r\n>>\r\n>>> test # 7\r\n>>>\r\n>>> On Thu, Dec 1, 2011 at 10:36 PM, paulo alvarado <\r\n>>> commonzenpython@gmail.com> wrote:\r\n>>>\r\n>>>> test # 6\r\n>>>>\r\n>>>>\r\n>>>> On Thu, Dec 1, 2011 at 10:36 PM, paulo alvarado <\r\n>>>> commonzenpython@gmail.com> wrote:\r\n>>>>\r\n>>>>> test # 5\r\n>>>>>\r\n>>>>>\r\n>>>>> On Thu, Dec 1, 2011 at 9:46 PM, paulo alvarado <\r\n>>>>> commonzenpython@gmail.com> wrote:\r\n>>>>>\r\n>>>>>> this is test # 4\r\n>>>>>>\r\n>>>>>>\r\n>>>>>>\r\n>>>>>> On Thu, Dec 1, 2011 at 7:13 PM, paulo alvarado <\r\n>>>>>> commonzenpython@gmail.com> wrote:\r\n>>>>>>\r\n>>>>>>> this is test # 1\r\n>>>>>>>\r\n>>>>>>\r\n>>>>>>\r\n>>>>>\r\n>>>>\r\n>>>\r\n>>\r\n>\r\n
```

as you can see test #10 is the new message, the other stuff are the previous replies
i am using python2.7

*EDIT*

I have a ticket application, so basically, i want the user to be able to submit tickets, via email, so the user's email is the author, the subject is the title, and the message body is the description, i have it all working fine except for how to handle a reply, because at this moment, if a user replies via email, the description of the ticket will not only contain the new issue ( or response ) but it will also contain the previous ones, so i want to know if there is a way to remove the previous responses and only keep the new one, heres a picture of my issue.

[image: As you can see, the description of the ticket contains the email's previous replies]

Comment: People are free to use any subject line they want when replying to mail messages. Mail clients may not use the `In-Reply-To` or `References` headers when replying -- or a user may simply hit "reply" to a message to get the `To:` header "for free", being unaware that the mail will be threaded in the wrong location. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: edited my question to include more information

Comment: Excellent. The new problem sounds solvable. :)

Comment: could you please provide an example or link i could use  ?

Answer (score -1):

Google comes up with

```
import imaplib
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host='mail.example.com')
# or conn =imaplib.IMAP4(host='mail.example.com') for no SSL 
try: 
    (retcode, capabilities) = conn.login('user', 'pass') 
except: 
    # cannot login
conn.select(readonly=1) # Select inbox or default namespace 
(retcode, messages) = conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)') 
if retcode == 'OK': 
    for message in messages[0].split(' '): 
        print 'Processing :', message 
        (ret, mesginfo) = conn.fetch(message, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM)])') 
        if ret == 'OK': 
            # process message here 
conn.close()
```

where `conn.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')` is the important piece in the code.